# Getting wrong file path when generating file route in C# Console App

Tags: c#, sql, file, console-application, readfile

I'm trying to read in a SQL script in a C# console app. I'm having issues as the file route that it's generating always starts in the bin folder of the project.

```cs
        public static void ApiResources(IConfiguration config, string testUrlExtension)
        {
            try
            {
                var azureDatabaseUrl = String.Format(config["SqlDatabase:BaseUrl"], $"test{testUrlExtension}");

                SqlConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                connBuilder.DataSource = azureDatabaseUrl;
                connBuilder.UserID = config["SqlDatabase:ZupaKeyReleaseUserName"];
                connBuilder.Password = config["SqlDatabase:ZupaKeyReleasePassword"];
                connBuilder.InitialCatalog = "zupaauthentication";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connBuilder.ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        var GetLocalPathToProject = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).Split("Zupa.ReleaseDeploymentAutoConfigure")[0];
                        var routeToApiResourseSqlScript = $"{GetLocalPathToProject}Zupa.ReleaseDeploymentAutoConfigure\\Zupa.ReleaseDeploymentAutoConfigure\\Sql\\Scripts\\";
                        var apiResourcesFileName = "AddApiResorces.sql";
                        var fullPathToSqlScript = $"{routeToApiResourseSqlScript}{apiResourcesFileName}";

                        command.CommandText = File.ReadAllText(fullPathToSqlScript);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
            }
        }
```

The error I'm receiving is as follows:

> Something went wrong try configuring the release again.
> System.IO.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. :
>
> 'C:\Zupa_Source_Code\Zupa.ReleaseDeploymentAutoConfigure\Zupa.ReleaseDeploymentAutoConfigure\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\file:\C:\Zupa_Source_Code\Zupa.ReleaseDeploymentAutoConfigure\Zupa.ReleaseDeploymentAutoConfigure\Sql\Scripts\AddApiResorces.sql'

The correct path is being added to the end of the bin directory which is

> file:\C:\Zupa_Source_Code\Zupa.ReleaseDeploymentAutoConfigure\Zupa.ReleaseDeploymentAutoConfigure\Sql\Scripts\AddApiResorces.sql

Comment: This is really not at the stage of asking a question, its still a debugging problem... Step through this code, inspect the variables, identify the problem, try to fix it

Comment: Well i know the issue dot net is running the project in debug from the bin folder so when the .getWrokingDirectory is called it prepends my file path with is correctly constructed to the random working directory of the project from where its running.

Comment: `file:\` doesn't look right to me which probably isn't helping things. Perhaps you meant [file:///](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "CodeBase" in this line

```
var GetLocalPathToProject = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).Split("Zupa.ReleaseDeploymentAutoConfigure")[0];
```

to be Location:

```
var GetLocalPathToProject = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Split("Zupa.ReleaseDeploymentAutoConfigure")[0];
```

Comment: This fixed the issue thanks for that not exactly sure why but its done the trick.